# mysql choose first record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | David   |
|  2 | Roz     |
|  3 | Patrick |
|  4 | Chris   |
|  5 | Agnes   |
|  6 | Freya   |
+----+---------+
```

How result first record my option.
example: I choose roz is first

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  2 | Roz     |
|  1 | David   |
|  3 | Patrick |
|  4 | Chris   |
|  5 | Agnes   |
|  6 | Freya   |
+----+---------+
```

or I choose first agnes

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  5 | Agnes   |
|  1 | David   |
|  2 | Roz     |
|  3 | Patrick |
|  4 | Chris   |
|  6 | Freya   |
+----+---------+
```

Comment: I don't see a question. What is it?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "first record" as long as you don't define an order (with the ORDER BY clause). Often used: an autoincrement column or a automatic timestamp on insert. But it could be a date of birth, the order of the names, ...

Comment: Dropping code and hoping for the best.

Answer (score 2):

something like this, your specific name, then the default sort for the rest

```
SELECT *
FROM `FOO`
ORDER BY (`name` = 'Roz') DESC, `name`
```

Comment: my english is not good but ı undurstand you. this answer is clearly. thanks @Dagon :) :)